# Understanding the effect of parent PLUS loan on the parent's credit score

Tags: loans, college

I am helping a family navigate paying for college and I have a question that I cannot seem to answer by searching this site or any of the federal sites.

Suppose the mom takes out a Parent PLUS loan for her daughter. There is the principal and also the interest that accrues while the student is in school. There is no obligation to make any payments while the student is enrolled.

Since the loan is debt, this will ding the mother's credit score. Can the effect be lessened by making payments on the interest while the student is still in school? Or is this hit mainly from having the large principal and making payments on the interest while in school pointless?

Links to any official explanation of this would be much appreciated.